# How to create a regex for number with at least 3 numbers and 2 decimals or more?

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that accept for example:

```
22.23566556 #Two digits before decimal point, and two or more decimals, accepted 
123.123 #Three digits before decimal point, and two or more decimals, accepted
1.00 #One number before decimal point, and two decimals, accepted
...
```

And non accepted numbers:

```
4564.1546 #Four digits before decimal point, not accepted
123.1 #Three digits before decimal point, but only one decimal, not accepted
...
```

I tried with:

```
import re

text = "212.12454"

result = re.search(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{2}?", text)
print(result.group())
```

But it return in console the number with two decimals:

```
212.12
```

And my expected output would be the whole number:

```
212.12454
```

I hope someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: It appears you want to match a string of digits containing one period  that has at most (not at least) three digits to the left of the period and at least two digits to the right of the period. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since the lower bound is 2 and upper bound does not matter `{2,}` can be used
Try,

```
import re

text = "212.12454"

result = re.search(r"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{2,}", text)
print(result.group())
```

Answer (score 0):

At last, you've typed only {2} which means it'll check for only two occurences. If you want 2 or more occurences, then you've to type {2,} which means it'll check for two or more